# How to check if a username exists in my Golang chain code for Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, identity, chaincode

In the chain code for Hyperledger Fabric, is it possible to check if an identity exists with a given name? that is, something like this:

```
func (c *SmartContract) UserExists(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, username string) bool {
     // if an identity exists with the username, then return true, otherwise return false.
}
```

Comment: By "identity" (or "user"), is this referring to user records that you have stored on the blockchain, or is it referring to cryptographic credentials (such as X.509 certificates) used to identify users submitting transactions?

Comment: The "identity" here, I mean a user registered in CA, with an X509 certificate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with the `IdentityService` provided `contractapi.TransactionContextInterface`. However, in fact identities in Hyperledger Fabric are typically managed by the MSP and not directly accessible within the chaincode. If you use identity-based access control within your Fabric network, then you can try the following approach.

```
//assuming that you've imported necessary packages

 func (c *SmartContract) UserExists(ctx contractapi.TransactionContextInterface, 
 username string) (bool, error) {
// Get the identity service from the transaction context
identityService, err := 
ctx.GetClientIdentity().GetSigningIdentity().CreateAccessControl()
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}

// Check if the identity exists with the given username
exists, err := identityService.GetState(username)
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}

return exists != nil, nil
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this works? I don't see a `GetSigningIdentity()` method on the ClientIdentity interface returned by `ctx.GetClientIdentity()`: https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/hyperledger/fabric-chaincode-go/pkg/cid#ClientIdentity